# How to unbind an jquery on('click','selector') event

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I've binded a class as follow,

```
$(document).on('click','.add-more',function(){
 alert('Do Something')
});
```

My requirement forces me to use .on('click') instead of click, bind('click') etc...  Now I want to unbind the click event.  Hope my question is clear.  Thanks in anticipation for support.

Comment: Just google it next time.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
$(document).off('click','.add-more');
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hzv21vex/)**

Answer (score 2):

You use `.off` with the **same selector** (to avoid removing unrelated things), and possibly the same function (again to avoid removing unrelated things):

```
// Removes ALL click handlers from `document` that handle `.add-more`
// elements via delegation
$(document).off('click','.add-more');
```

If you need to be sure just to remove a *specific* function, you do that:

```
function handler() {
 alert('Do Something')
}

// If previously you did
// $(document).on('click','.add-more',handler);
// then:
$(document).off('click','.add-more',handler);
```

There, only the specific handler is removed (not other `click` handlers on `document` that handle `.add-more` via delegation).

Comment: TJ, how to add handler parameters in this part `$(document).on('click','.add-more',handler);`? If I use anonym function, the removing handler fails.

Comment: @JeafGilbert: Name the function so you can use the same one with `off`, or use an event namespace; more: http://api.jquery.com/on/.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `.off` to unbind event bound with `.on`

```
$(document).off('click');
```

here are the [full docs](http://api.jquery.com/off/)